# 'git rm -r --cached bin/' is not working

Tags: git, gitignore, git-rm

When I type:

> git rm -r --cached bin/

I get the following:

> fatal: pathspec 'bin/' did not match any files

The folder exists. I don't know why this is not working. I've found several answers that say this is the correct syntax.

Comment: What's the output of `git status`?

Comment: on branch master - nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: The --cached option only removes files from the index, files that have been staged for commit. So what you have above is correct as your git status says your working directory is clean. Have a look at the manual page - https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, first make sure that it's actually added to the index:

```
git add bin
```

Then execute your command to remove it:

```
git rm -r --cached bin/
```

If the problem persists:

> git reset --hard